# Remove currency symbol of price type product attribute from admin product form

Tags: product-attribute, magento-2.2.5, currency

I've added price type product attribute for the product sorting, here is the screenshot:-

http://nimb.ws/Wqat3J

How can I remove currency symbol?

Waiting for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

I've removed using CSS because it was simpler.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i create plugin afterGetMeta from file
Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\ProductDataProvider
and i unset config addbefore of attribute
[image]